# Como usar el comando insert into user(host, user, authentication_string)?

Tags: mysql, sql, appserv

Se me pidio "Crea un usuario llamado administrador con password adminies y que se conecte desde localhost modificando directamente las tablas de permisos. Inserta sólo las columnas host, user y password.Antes de ejecutar flush privileges, sal y entra de nuevo en mysql con el usuario administrador ycomprueba que los permisos no se aplican hasta que se recargan las tablas de privilegios. "
pero cada vez que quiero usar el "insert into user" sale un mensaje de database not selected.

Comment: intenta colocando primero el `use nombreBaseDatos;`

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad y de paso vas ganando reputación.